# Fully mask *all* traces of WordPress installation subdirectory?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, installation

As can be seen in this [dem0site.net](http://dem0site.net) (which has been installed to its own subdirectory (`public_html/wp-org-01/`), I have successfully followed the Codex instructions for ["giving WordPress its own directory" (using a pre-existing subdirectory install)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install).

The site's externally-visible URL has been changed from `http://dem0site.net/wp-org-01` to simply http://dem0site.net. And the "pretty permalinks" to individual posts also appear the way I want them to -- for example: http://dem0site.net/hello-world/.

However, I would like to get rid of **all** external traces of the '**wp-org-01/**' installation-subdirectory, which still show up:

1. when hovering over the '**Site Admin**' element of the 'Meta' widget, which shows: http://dem0site.net/wp-org-01/wp-login.php
2. for images and other items in the '**uploads**' directory, such as http://dem0site.net/wp-org-01/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/WordPressOrgIcon1.png.

Is it possible to **fully** mask all such external traces of installation-subdirectory, using just '.htaccess' and standard WordPress settings, but without relying on any plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of anyone interested in the answer to this question, I am posting here the following answer that I received in the [WordPress.org support forums](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174509/fully-mask-all-traces-of-wordpress-installation-subdirectory).

[leejosepho](http://www.noname8.net/index.html) graciously provided the following answer:

> Yes, that is possible. Save 'http://dem0site.net' in both boxes at Dashboard > Settings > General, then cPanel-assign and -point your domain to public_html and use this htaccess to redirect it to 'wp-org-01' (or wherever):

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
## index.php for WordPress
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

> Visitors to your Web site will not be able to tell that your main domain is using a subdirectory, they will still see the Web site address as http://www.example.com/... 
>   https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347#redirect